# Find table information where part of column matches char variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find any tables with columns containing the word `date` somewhere in the column name.

All of my queries are either all or nothing: they return all tables in the DB, or no results at all.

When I run a query without the variable, it works, as seen here.

```
select  *
from MyDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where column_name like '%date%'
```

However, I can't get it to work by using a variable.

```
declare @temp varchar = 'date'
select*
from MyDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where column_name like '%' + @temp + '%'
```

The reason I'd like to do this is because I need to run this on more than one DB (such as below), and I have to perform this several times (for more than just `date`), and I'd like the process to go more smoothly.

```
    select  *
    from MyDB1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    where column_name like '%date%'
union all
    select  *
    from MyDB2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    where column_name like '%date%'
union all
    select  *
    from MyDB3.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    where column_name like '%date%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One query with cursor to loop through all the database on your server or you can explicitly loop through certain database

### Query

```
DECLARE @DB_Name SYSNAME;
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)= '';


DECLARE @cur CURSOR;

SET @Cur = CURSOR FOR
SELECT name 
FROM sys.sysdatabases
--WHERE name IN ('DBName1', 'DBName2', 'DBName3');  --<-- uncomment this line and 
                                                      -- specify the database names
OPEN @cur

FETCH NEXT FROM @Cur INTO @DB_Name 

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
   SET @Sql = N'
SELECT t.name 
      ,c.name 
FROM '+ QUOTENAME(@DB_Name) + '.sys.tables  t 
INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(@DB_Name) + '.sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE t.name LIKE ''%test%'''

    EXEC(@Sql)

   FETCH NEXT FROM @Cur INTO @DB_Name 
END

CLOSE @cur
DEALLOCATE @cur
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use what ever source of column info you prefer but the issue you are having is because of your variable declaration.

declare @temp varchar = 'date' is equivalent to 
declare @temp varchar(1) = 'date' so
select @temp returns 'd' so you are getting any columns containing 'd'

when you declare your variable make sure it has a length that is sufficient to store the longest of the strings you will be searching for. Jason's answer will work too but it is because of the variable declaration not the source of the data.

Answer (score 0):

I guess problem is with your variable declaration part.

By default any variable declared with datatype **VARCHAR** will be considered as **VARCHAR(1)** in SQLServer.

```
declare @temp varchar = 'date'
print @temp --d
```

So try declaring your variable as **VARCHAR(4)**.

```
declare @temp varchar(4) = 'date'
print @temp --date
```